# $(...).validate is not a function with jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run the jQuery Validation plugin. I have looked at every other question on stack or GitHub I could find and none seem to have the exact same issue. 
I import jQuery and the Validate in the correct order with:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

I checked and they get correctly and fully loaded in the browser network tab.
Even with the most basic code (the form with id='project_form' exists):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#project_form").validate({
     debug:true
  });
});`
```

the validate function doesn't work and results in the `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).validate is not a function` warning and `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` error.

Where could the error be?

Comment: Please use the search function before posting a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this error may be come because of more than one js load so kindly check , if not more than one js load in the page So it happens because of jquery version 3.X.X(you are using 3.4.1) so please use any other version of jquery , it will resolve your problem thank you

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice because jQuery was was also included in my app.js. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: always welcome:)